# How to provide a custom controller to a redmine hook view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hook, redmine, redmine-plugins

I wrote a redmine hook view that adds fields in the bottom of issue description.
My hook view needs to pull its data from another controller than the issue controller.

I used this code to create my hook:

```
module RedmineKnowledgebase
class Hooks < Redmine::Hook::ViewListener
def view_issues_show_description_bottom(context = {})
context[:controller].send(:render_to_string, {
:partial => " redmine_plugin_xxx/hooks/view_issues_show_
description_bottom",
:locals => context
})
end
end
end
```

In my hook view, I have table to be filled:

```
<tbody>
    <% @ok_results.each do |res| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= res.id %></td>
        <td><%= res.key %></td>
        <td><%= res.value %></td>      
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Basically, my @ok_results variable should be provided by controller that use a couchdb rest model not by the issue controller.

The controller that should provide the @ok_results variable is as follows:

```
class RequirementsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_requirement, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /requirements
  # GET /requirements.json
  def index
    #@requirements = requirement.all
    #Requirement.create(:first_name => "Homer", :last_name => "Simpson")
  end

  # GET /requirements/1
  # GET /requirements/1.json
  def show
  end

  def ok_result
    @ok_results = Requirement.ok_result.rows
  end

  def by_topic
    @by_topic_record = Requirement.by_topic.rows
  end

  def by_requirement_no
  @by_req_record = Requirement.by_requirement_no.rows
  end

  # GET /requirements/new
  def new
    @requirement = Requirement.new
  end

  # GET /requirements/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /requirements
  # POST /requirements.json
  def create
    @requirement = Requirement.new(requirement_params)
    print requirement_params[:name]
    print requirement_params[:email]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @requirement.save
        format.html { redirect_to @requirement, notice: 'requirement was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @requirement }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @requirement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and my couch db model which is related to the above controller is as follows:

```
require 'couchrest_model'

class Requirement < CouchRest::Model::Base
  use_database 'raw_files'
  property :requirement_no, String
  property :test_case, Array
  property :topic, Array
  property :round_1, Array
  property :ecupn, Array
  property :sim_tool_pn, Array
  property :details, Array
  design do
    view :by_topic, :map => "function(doc){if(doc.topic){emit(doc.topic,doc.details)}}"
    view :by_requirement_no, :map => "function(doc){if(doc.requirement_no){emit(doc.requirement_no,doc.test_case)}}"
    view :ok_result,
      :map =>
        "function(doc) {
          if (doc['requirement_no']) {
            doc.round_1.forEach(function(res, index){
                if(res == 'OK')
                emit(doc.requirement_no, [doc.test_case[index], doc.topic[index]]);
            });
          }
        }"
  end
  timestamps!

end
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: How is the data stored that you would like to pull to your issue_controller?
Can you show the other controller and the data?

Comment: @PeterAndersen I updated the issue by adding my controller and my model

Comment: I can't help you sorry. I have never seen a model like that before.